# Using wildcard to select field by suffix and do a condition (endswith)

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, wildcard

With this validation I get the fields from my active Layer and put into the parameter after select the layer

```
if self.params[0].value:
  self.params[1].filter.list = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(self.params[0].value,
                                                                wild_card='APH*')]
return
```

My operations depends only from the year (suffix) (considering I already choose only the fields I need by Validation).

I tried many ways to solve this, but always get errors like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Agro\Scripts\PercAPH.py", line 19, in <module>
    if field1.name('*2003') and lyr.symbologyType == "GRADUATED_COLORS":
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'name'
Failed to execute (PercAPH).
```

I know it`s very clear that the object do not have this function, but I read some documentations from ESRI website and the code examples uses field.name for example. In my last attempt I use the 'endswith' but the same error appears.

Here is my last code attempt. I will repeat this code for N years from my attribute table.

```
TabelaP1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Ano = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) #field 'Ano' list all year fields using Validation
IndexL = int(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2))
SiglaProduto = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "")[0]
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)[IndexL]
Layer1 = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r'F:\Agro\Layers\PercAPH.lyr')
field1 = for f in fields arcpy.ListFields(TabelaP1)

arcpy.AddMessage('Calculando Porcentagem de Area Plantada')

if field1.endswith('*2003') and lyr.symbologyType == "GRADUATED_COLORS":

NovoCampo1 = 'Perc_'+SiglaProduto+'_APH2003'
Campo1 = 'Ano'
arcpy.AddMessage('Campo selecionado: {0}'.format(Campo1))
arcpy.AddField_management(TabelaP1, NovoCampo1, 'Float')
arcpy.CalculateField_management(TabelaP1, NovoCampo1, '(!Ano!/!AreaTotalHec!)*100', "PYTHON_9.3")
lyr.symbology.valueField = NovoCampo1
arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, lyr, Layer1, True)
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

Comment: In your code `field1` is a list, you need to be performing your operations, e.g. `endswith()` or whatever you choose, on the items within the list not the actual list.

Comment: GeoSharp, I didn`t understand. Can you give me some example please?

Comment: Your list contains items that are strings. You can perform `.endswith()` on the string objects within your list, but not on the list. e.g. `[x.endswith('t') for x in field1]` works because you are operating on the individual string objects in the list, `field1.endswith('t')` does not work because a list does not have a method `endswith()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, here is a code snippet that should bring some clarity to the exception you are receiving:

```
for field in field1:
    if field.name.endswith('*2003'):
        #do something
```

[`arcpy.ListFields()`](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/listfields.htm) returns a list of [`Field` objects](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/field.htm). `Field` objects have a `name` attribute that is a string. [`string` objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) have a method [`endswith()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_endswith.htm). Click on any of the text highlighted in blue for further documentation about that subject.

So in your case `field1` is a list of `Field` objects. You need to use a loop or [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) to perform operations on the individual `Field` objects that are in your variable `field1`. Further **`endswith()` does not support wildcards**, `*`, as you have in your code. You will need to use a different method to filter out the string you are trying to get at. I would look into using [regular expressions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm), the following regular expression can be used to match any string that ends with 4 digits:

```
\d{4}$
```

Comment: GeoSharp, many thanks for the detailed explain! I already get your ideias and my code works as expected now!